# Which hemisphere based on latitude and longitude

Tags: gps, coordinates

I have GPS coordinates (latitude and longitude) of a specific point, and i would like to know how can i determine if this point is located in the north or southern hemisphere ?

**Example :**

```
latitude : 45.760554

longitude : 4.836211

Expected Result : North hemisphere
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If latitude is positive, the position is on the northern hemisphere, if it is negative, it is on the southern hemisphere.